# Oracle procedure with input parameter that performs multiple SUBSTR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, substring

I have a table `Employee` with the columns `employee_id` as type `number`, and  `employee_name` as type `varchar`.

I need a procedure that takes an input string to insert employees into the table. The procedure should read and analyze the string which will include multiple names separated by commas.

**Example:**

```
'adam,alex,hales,jordan,jackob'
```

Each name should be extracted up until the comma and inserted into the employees table. So basically using the input string above I should have the names inserted as in the following result:

```
 employee_id | employee_name
-------------+--------------
 1           | adam
 2           | alex
 3           | hales
 4           | jordan
 5           | jackob
```

Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a procedure, you can do this in a single SQL statement (though you could wrap that statement in a procedure if necessary):

> ```
> insert into employee(employee_name)
> with w as (select 'adam,alex,hales,jordan,jackob' names from dual)
> select regexp_substr(names,'[^,]+', 1, level) from w
> connect by regexp_substr(names, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
> ```

> ```
> select * from employee;
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPLOYEE_ID | EMPLOYEE_NAME
> ----------: | :------------
>           1 | adam         
>           2 | alex         
>           3 | hales        
>           4 | jordan       
>           5 | jackob
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc370bbd85eadd42da5b369b9eacf552)*